# Group by Date mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of data in mongoDB that I have to sum up grouped by `$timestamp`. This field contains a date, but's formatted as String (example data above).

How should I proceed to convert `$timestamp` into a date so I can group them all together?

Next, I have to sum each `scores_today` for each date and iden, and the same with each `scores_total`.

Example data:

```
[
    {
        _id: "1442",
        timestamp: "2016-03-15T22:24:02.000Z",
        iden: "15",
        scores_today: "0.000000",
        scores_total: "52337.000000"
    }
]
```

My code

```
var project = {
            "$project":{ 
                "_id": 0,
                "y": {
                    "$year": "$timestamp"      // tried this way, not working
                    },
                "m": {
                    "$month": new Date("$timestamp") // tried either this, not working
                }, 
                "d": {
                    "$dayOfMonth":  new Date("$timestamp")
                },
                "iden" : "$iden"
            } 
        },
        group = {   
            "$group": { 
                "_id": { 
                    "iden" : "$iden",
                    "year": "$y", 
                    "month": "$m", 
                    "day": "$d"
                },  
                "count" : { "$sum" : "$scores_today" }
            }
        };
        mongoDB.collection('raw').aggregate([ project, group ]).toArray()....
```

This is the error logged by node.js service

> Err:  { [MongoError: exception: can't convert from BSON type String to
>   Date]   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'exception: can\'t convert from
>   BSON type String to Date',   errmsg: 'exception: can\'t convert from
>   BSON type String to Date',   code: 16006,   ok: 0 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct Date object from string using `ISODate($timestamp)`.

```
var project = {
            "$project":{ 
                "_id": 0,
                "y": {
                    "$year": ISODate("$timestamp").getFullYear()
                    },
                "m": {
                    "$month": ISODate("$timestamp").getMonth()+1 // months start from 0
                }, 
                "d": {
                    "$dayOfMonth":  ISODate("$timestamp").getDate()
                },
                "iden" : "$iden"
            } 
        },
        group = {   
            "$group": { 
                "_id": { 
                    "iden" : "$iden",
                    "year": "$y", 
                    "month": "$m", 
                    "day": "$d"
                },  
                "count" : { "$sum" : "$scores_today" }
            }
        };
```

**UPDATE**

If you're not running MongoDb shell then you can't use ISODate directly. In this case try to invoke eval command.

```
var aggregationResult=mongoDB.eval(
'
'function()                                                                                '+
'{                                                                                         '+
'  var project = {                                                                         '+
'              "$project":{                                                                '+ 
'                  "_id": 0,                                                               '+
'                  "y": {                                                                  '+
'                      "$year": ISODate("$timestamp").getFullYear()                        '+
'                      },                                                                  '+
'                  "m": {                                                                  '+
'                      "$month": ISODate("$timestamp").getMonth()+1 // months start from 0 '+
'                  },                                                                      '+
'                  "d": {                                                                  '+
'                      "$dayOfMonth":  ISODate("$timestamp").getDate()                     '+
'                  },                                                                      '+
'                  "iden" : "$iden"                                                        '+
'              }                                                                           '+
'          },                                                                              '+
'          group = {                                                                       '+
'              "$group": {                                                                 '+
'                  "_id": {                                                                '+
'                      "iden" : "$iden",                                                   '+
'                      "year": "$y",                                                       '+
'                      "month": "$m",                                                      '+
'                      "day": "$d"                                                         '+
'                  },                                                                      '+
'                  "count" : { "$sum" : "$scores_today" }                                  '+
'              }                                                                           '+
'          };  
'    var result=db.raw.aggregate([ project, group ]);                  '+
'    return result;                                                                        '+        
'  }                                                                                       '+
'
);
```

Comment: It gives me this 

`ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined`

Comment: @a.ndrea If you type in mongo CLI just `ISODate();` what result you will see?

Comment: @a.ndrea Well, try to put "$timestamp" in quotes.

Comment: I can't access mongo CLI, it's not on my pc and I don't have access there. Tried even "$timestamp", still the same error, ISODate is not defined

Comment: Ok, what client you're using? If it is not a mongo CLI then you can't use its functions in code as is, you must pass them to mongo in such a way that they will be called when aggregation runs. I guess, you can do it only passing all your aggregation script in eval().

Comment: I'm actually working with nodejs, using mongodb modules version 2.1.7. Related? Sorry, my first time with mongo. If I need eval(), how would it be like?

Comment: You can try to use Date Operators https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators. I never used them, check if they can parse string to date object.

Comment: @a.ndrea Added script for running eval(). Please, try it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience. After this mongoDb.eval I get a Promise. What do I have to do with this aggregationResult ?

Comment: @a.ndrea And what is there? I guess there is some object that you need to convert to array `aggregationResult.toArray()` as in your initial post. See what's there and then use it as you were going to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106396/discussion-between-a-ndrea-and-evgeny-s).