# How do you group by isodate year, month, day?

Tags: mongodb, isodate

How to group by isodate, preferably by year, month, day?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by Date mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020009/group-by-date-mongodb)

Answer (score 4):

I am adding a simple group query, will count the number of entries for each date. Refer the following documentation for more date operators. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation-date/

```
db.getCollection('callmodels').aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {day: {$dayOfMonth :"$date" }, month: {$month :"$date" }, year: {$year :"$date" }}, count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```